# Why is cURL not installed by default?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, curl

Many applications require `curl` or `libcurl` for running or installation. Why does Ubuntu not provide it by default?

Comment: Why should it be, when `wget` works as well? Also, different package, but same question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/580812/why-is-wget-still-shipped-as-the-default-download-manger-whereas-theres-richer

Comment: Generally, "why is <package> not installed by default" is not a good enough question without specifying what problem you are suffering as a result of it not being installed by default - and why you don't want to just install it.

Answer (score 4):

If an Ubuntu application requires curl, it will list it as a dependency in the package management system, ensuring it is installed automatically when installing that application.

Answer (score 2):

> Many applications require curl or libcurl for running or installation. Why does Ubuntu not provide it by default?

Because those applications are not installed by default in Ubuntu.  So there is no need for cURL to be installed on a vanilla Ubuntu.